# Android development using Google Tag Manager and dataLayer

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

I'm new to this Google Tag Manager stuff and I kinda got my ears tangled trying to test it.
Here's what I've done:

1. Created a GTM account;
2. Created a container;
3. Created a custom image tag;
4. Added rule always to the custom image tag;

Now here's my code:

```
package com.google.android.tagmanager.examples.helloworld;

import com.google.tagmanager.Container;
import com.google.tagmanager.ContainerOpener;
import com.google.tagmanager.ContainerOpener.OpenType;
import com.google.tagmanager.TagManager;
import com.google.tagmanager.DataLayer;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.Info;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import java.io.IOException;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.telephony.*;
import android.provider.*;

/**
 * An {@link Activity} that reads background and text color from a local
 * Json file and applies those colors to text view.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


  private static final String TAG = "GTMExample";
  private static final String CONTAINER_ID = "GTM-PJNXHL";

  private static final String OS = "os";
  private static final String DEVICE_IMEI = "device_imei";
  private static final String DEVICE_ANDROID_ID = "device_android_id";
  private static final String GOOGLE_AD_ID = "google_ad_id";

  private static  String deviceImei  = "";
  private static  String androidId   = "";
  private static  String googleAdId  = "";

  // Set to false for release build.
  private static final Boolean DEVELOPER_BUILD = true;
  private Container container;
  private DataLayer dataLayer;
  private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (DEVELOPER_BUILD) {
      StrictMode.enableDefaults();
    }

    // iau singletonul de tagmanager
    TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(this);

    ContainerOpener.ContainerFuture containerFuture = ContainerOpener.openContainer(
        tagManager, CONTAINER_ID, OpenType.PREFER_NON_DEFAULT, null);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    // This call may block (for up to the timeout specified in
    // ContainerOpener.openContainer). For an example that shows how to use a splash
    // screen to avoid blocking, see cuteanimals example.
    container = containerFuture.get();

    dataLayer = tagManager.getDataLayer();   

    // Modify the background-color and text-color of text based on the value
    // from configuration.
    updateVars();
  }

  private void updateVars() {
    Log.i(TAG, "image_test");
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_world);
    textView.setText(OS);
  }


  public void colorButtonClicked(View view) {
    Log.i(TAG, "colorButtonClicked");
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Getting vars");

    deviceImei =  telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    androidId  =  Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    Info adInfo = null;
    try {
      adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(this.getBaseContext().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    googleAdId = adInfo.getId();

    alertDialog.setMessage(deviceImei);

    dataLayer.push(DEVICE_IMEI, deviceImei);
    dataLayer.push(DEVICE_ANDROID_ID, androidId);
    dataLayer.push(GOOGLE_AD_ID, googleAdId);

    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
        "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
    updateVars();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
  }
}
```

What I want is to push the deviceImei, androidId and googleAdId using DataLayer.

My questions are:

1. How do I test and see that the data is pushed using dataLayer?
2. How do I test and see if the tag has been fired with the data from the dataLayer?
3. Where do I test to see that the tag has been traked?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use Google Analytics event with your data and the same rule. You'll see your data in GA if everything is correct.

Comment: You can use your data in category, action and label fields of Google Analytics event tag. So if all data is correct you'll it in Events report in Google Analytics

Comment: @ mrbubu,Can you post one example how we can achieve this.

Comment: Pankaj,  Just to be clear, do you need an example of Google Tag Manager settings?